# Why there's a NOT in the test part and no incrementation in the incrementation part of the "for" loop of free() in 8.7 of K&R?

Tags: c

This is the "for" loop in the free() function on p.188 of K&R:

```
for (p = freep; !(bp > p && bp < p->s.ptr); p = p->s.ptr)
  if (p >= p->s.ptr && (bp > p || bp < p->s.ptr))
    break;
```

Instead of !(bp > p && bp < p->s.ptr) why not write bp < p && bp > p->s.ptr?
Also why doesn't this loop have an incrementation?

Comment: At least for the second part, `for` loops don't always use increments, although that's a common case. If you were iterating a linked list for example, you could have a loop like `for(Node* cur = node; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next) {` (assuming a `Node` struct that has a `next` member). That actually looks like what's happening here.

Comment: `!(bp > p && bp < p->s.ptr) why not write bp < p && bp > p->s.ptr?` Mostly because that's different.

Comment: `!(bp > p && bp < p->s.ptr)` is *not* equivalent to `bp < p && bp > p->s.ptr`.  It's equivalent to `bp <= p || bp >= p->s.ptr`.  Do the case analysis.  You should be able to confirm this for yourself:  `!(a && b)` is equivalent to `!a || !b`.  This follows directly from [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).  See if you can work it out on paper.  And note that `!(a > b)` is `a <= b`, not `a < b`.

Comment: Also, the `for` loop *does* have an increment expression.  It's `p = p->s.ptr`, which steps `p` to the next object.  That's exactly what increment code should do.

Comment: The posted code looks like Brian & Dennis at their very best! In their day, C was never intended for the faint-hearted!

Comment: It doesn't follow from DeMorgan, it *is* DeMorgan.